# Copying pattern from set of lines with Vim's Ex mode

Tags: regex, vim, vi, ex

I am tidying up my vimrc.

**Mission:
 - Copy content inside single-quotes (and preferably after the slash)

- Paste them below line 1**

```
1: Name:
2: 
3: Bundle 'tpope/vim-rails'
4: Bundle 'tpope/vim-endwise'
5: Bundle 'mileszs/ack.vim'
6: Bundle 'scrooloose/nerdcommenter'
7: Bundle 'kana/vim-textobj-entire'
8: Bundle 'kana/vim-textobj-user'
```

I know about the

```
:{source_address}t{target_address}
```

Ex command, and I know it accepts patterns. However, I am still not able to get it just right. I am also fairly new to regexes so bear with me. I tried something along the lines of (on a visual selection

```
:'<,'>/\/.*\'t1
```

Where I attempt to match a pattern that:

- Starts with a /
- May contain stuff in the middle .*
- Ends with a '

Obviously I am off by some degree. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`:t` copy the whole line, not the `matchstr`

to achieve what you want, you need `matchstr()` function.

this line will do the similar thing, but in reverse order. Hope it is ok for you:

```
:'<,'>g/\/.*'/call append(1,matchstr(getline('.'),@/))
```

for example, if I just select the first two "Bundle" lines, and execute the cmd, I get:

```
1: Name:
/vim-endwise'
/vim-rails'
2: 
3: Bundle 'tpope/vim-rails'
4: Bundle 'tpope/vim-endwise'
.... (other lines)
```

you see that the order was in reverse.

To keep the order you have options :

- write script with list
- select those "reversed" lines, and do `'<,'>g/.*/m1`
- assign the matchstr to reg x, and `2put! x`

Comment: Would you care to explain your append-parameters? From what I can make of it:

Param 1: Destination.
Param 2: Content.

 Content here being the result of the matchstr-function, which here basically gets the current line ., and returns whatever corresponds with the pattern from the previous search @/
Is that correct?

Comment: yes, it did something like that. you can `:h append(` and `:h matchstr(` to get detailed para info. @krystah

Answer (score 2):

1. Yank the block.
2. Put it where you want it.
3. Remove what you don't want.

Assuming the cursor is somewhere on line 1:

```
:3,8t.
:'[,norm dt/$x
```

Explanation:

- `'[` and `']` mark the beginning and the end of the latest change.
- We want the range to start on the first `Bundle` line so we start it with the `'[` mark. We could simply use `2` instead, but that's less "magical".
- It ends with the current line which we can omit because it's the default value.
- We use `:normal` to execute normal mode commands from the command-line.
- We delete until the first `/` (`dt/`) and delete the last char on the line (`$x)` in one go.

Another way:

```
:3,8t.
v'[
:'<,'>s/.*\/\(.*\)'/\1 ('<,'> being inserted automatically)
```

Comment: This works, but I was attempting to make a precise extraction from the string, as I already knew how to process the String when I had already moved it. Just my laziness. Nice heads up on the '[ :)

Answer (score 0):

The problem with what you're doing is that ex commands work on lines, not on parts of lines like you're thinking. You can't use the `:t` command directly like that to copy what you need.

There's probably a way to do exactly what you're thinking, but here's what I would do to accomplish what you want: copy *all* of lines 3-8, paste them below line 1, and then isolate the text you're interested in.

There's a bunch of ways to copy a range of lines. If you need help with that, comment and ask.

Now how do we isolate the part in the quotes after the slash? We can just do a substitution, using basically the same pattern you wrote:

```
:'<,'>s/.*\/\(.*\)'/\1
```

Answer (score 0):

The `:t` / `:copy` commands (as most Ex commands) always copy *entire lines*, not parts of it. For that, you need `:substitute`, and use side effects in its replace expression to gather them in a register. The [Copy the search results into clipboard](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Copy_the_search_results_into_clipboard) Vim Tips Wiki page explains this.

With my [ExtractMatches plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=4795), this is quite easy to do, though:

```
:3,$YankMatchesToReg#/\zs.*\ze'#
:1put
```

This uses the `/.*'` pattern, and restricts the match (with the `\zs` and `\ze` atoms) to exclude the leading slash and trailing quote.

Without the plugin, it's probably easier to copy the full lines and then prune the undesired content with `:s`, as shown in @pandubear's answer.